# На основе какой логики следует принимать решение о создании дополнительных папок в Docker-контейнерах от образов NodeJS?

Tags: docker

Сколько я не вижу уроков по Docker, практически везде в контейнере создаются дополнительные папки, в которую кладётся проект. Вот пример: содержимое директорий `src` и `dist`:

```
├── dist
│   └── bundle.js
├── docker
│   └── webpack
│       ├── Dockerfile
│       ├── package.json
│       └── webpack.config.js
├── docker-compose.yml
└── src
    ├── app.js
    └── test.js
```

нужно зачем-то обязательно положить в папку `my_webpack`, имя которой "самоочевидное и сразу понятно, зачем она нужна":

```
version: '3'

services:
  webpack:
    build: ./docker/webpack
    volumes:
      - ./src:/my_webpack/src
      - ./dist:/my_webpack/dist
      - ./docker/webpack/package.json:/my_webpack/package.json
      - ./docker/webpack/webpack.config.js:/my_webpack/webpack.config.js
    ports:
      - 2000:2000
```

Другой [пример](https://properdesign.co.uk/developing-a-new-node-module-in-a-docker-container-without-using-npm-link/):

```
volumes:
- .:/usr/src/app
```

У нас же в контейнере ничего, кроме приложения нет! Какую такую жизненную необходимость имеет матрёшка `usr/src/app`?

В будущем я буду использовать в основном образы Node.js и если это не даёт никаких побочных эффектов, то класть своё приложение прямо в корень файловой системы контейнера. Будут ли у Вас, дорогие Docker-специалисты, какие-нибудь аргументы в пользу того, что так делать нельзя?

### Обновление

Из этого [англоязычного ответа](https://properdesign.co.uk/developing-a-new-node-module-in-a-docker-container-without-using-npm-link/) я узнал, что ничего примонтировать к корневой директории контейнера нельзя. Поэтому если нам нужно что-то примонтировать, то возникает необходимость создать как минимум одну директорию в контейнере.

Comment: в линуксе/юниксе есть общепринятые места расположения определенных файлов. То, что бинарник приложения будет находится в `/usr/local/...` - очевидно. А если он будет находится в `/tmp/mycoolapp` - нет.

Comment: @KoVadim а какой смысл следовать общепринятым местам в докере?

Comment: ну давайте переходить дорогу где попало. Если сторонний человек посмотрит на Ваш докер файл/образ, он быстро догадается, что где, если оно соответствует общепринятому. Да и Вам в будущем будет легче понимать. К тому же в линуксе некоторые папки имеют разные права и может оказаться, что файл не запускается и это потому, что каталог не дает права на выполнение или целевой каталог доступен только для чтения.

Comment: @KoVadim в пределах своей частной территории все именно то и делают, что переходят дорогу где попало :) Лично я вот совершенно ни о чём не догадаюсь, если вместо компактного `/app` программа будет пораспихана куда-то по глубинам линукса (да и вообще Filesystem Hierarchy Standard я считаю ущербным)

Comment: ну тогда делайте как считаете нужным. Кто же Вам запретит. Возможно, в будущем именно Ваша схема размещения файлов статен стандартом де факто.

Comment: @KoVadim, с Linux-ом всё понятно. Не буду принимать участие в Вашем горячем обсуждении ввиду своей низкой квалификации, а вот чтобы подвести этот вопрос к логическому завершению, спрошу, имеет ли смысл придерживаться в контейнерах от образа NodeJS (например, `node:12.4`) тех же правил организации файлов , что и в образах от Linux. Если ответ будет "Нет, можно класть приложение прямо в корень", то вопрос исчерпан. Если ответ "нет, нужно обязательно добавлять "usr/src/app", как и Linux", то тогда я поинтересуюсь, какое положительное влияние это оказывает.

Comment: не буду принимать участие в столь странном вопросе, скажу только что все выше я уже написал. Но в любом случае, прямо в корень бросать весь свой код точно не стоит.  хотя бы папку создать для него, хоть в корне. Это же контейнер, а не мусорка. А нет, стоп, это же контейнер.